# How to remove values below a threshold on ggplot2 pie chart but keep them in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am looking to set up a threshold so that values below 250 aren't shown in a pie chart that I have created.

[image: Cluttered Pie Chart]

Thanks in advance

Example data:

| Families | Quantities |
| --- | --- |
| Pomacentridae | 19056 |
| Gobiidae | 8000 |
| Labridae | 7990 |
| Labrisomidae | 3 |
| Zanclidae | 277 |

Here is my code :

```
   plot18 <- ggplot(data= Family_Quantities, aes(x = "", y = 
   Quantities, fill = Families)) +
   geom_col(color = "black") +
   geom_text_repel(aes(label = Quantities),
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
   coord_polar(theta = "y") +
   theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank())+
    theme_void()
```

Comment: Try just subsetting your data: `ggplot(data = Family_Quantities[Family_Quantities$Quantities > 250,], aes(...)`

Comment: Unfortunately that also removes them from the key, which i need to include them within. Therefore this did not work

Comment: A pie chart may be used to describe proportions within a data set but it does not make much sense to remove data (hence change the proportions) if you insist on using a pie chart you can (A) merge small categories and label them as "other", (B) show all categories but no label for smaller categories, (C) explain why exactly you need a pie chart so that we can figure out if it is actually the appropriate type of figure. Happy to help if can pick between (A), (B) and (C).

Comment: I would say that B makes the most sense for my use case. When you refer to showing all categories but having no label for it, are you referring to their position on the chart? If so, that is what I believe will apply best. I will explain why a pie chart anyway. I am doing a report upon ornamental fish that have been exported from a range of countries and it includes around 65 families of fish. This will be an introductory graph to visualise the scope of ornamental fish that have been exported, I feel as if this shows that well as it presents all families that can be found within the trade.

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, I don't think this solution is really appropriate but it does solve your problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

t <- tribble(~Families,  ~Quantities,
             "Pomacentridae",  19056,
             "Gobiidae",        8000,
             "Labridae",        7990,
             "Labrisomidae",       3,
             "Zanclidae",        277)

t |>
  # make Families a factor to be able to preserve all levels
  mutate(Families=factor(Families)) |>
  # remove the data you don't want to show
  filter(Quantities>250) |>
  ggplot(aes(1, Quantities, fill = Families)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Quantities),
                  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  # add the drop=F option to your filling scale, this will
  # ensure all levels of the factor are shown in the legend
  scale_fill_discrete(drop=F) +
  theme_void()
```